# How to fetch resultset from db2 stored procedure with help of out parameters or local variables

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, cognos

I have written a stored procedure as follows :

```
create procedure return_dates
(in date_range_string char(50),
in report_id integer
)
language sql
dynamic result sets 2

begin
DECLARE paid_strt_dt varchar(250);
DECLARE paid_end_dt varchar(250);
DECLARE c1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR s1;
DECLARE c2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR s2;

if date_range_string='prior month' then
    set paid_strt_dt = 'select (current date - 1 month) + 1 days - day(current date - 1 month) days from sysibm.sysdummy1';
    set paid_end_dt = 'select current date - day(current date) days from sysibm.sysdummy1';
end if;

PREPARE s1 FROM paid_strt_dt;
OPEN c1;

PREPARE s2 FROM paid_end_dt;
OPEN c2;
end
```

I am getting error which says my prepare statement contains empty string. I am trying to import this stored procedure as a query subject in cognos framework manager and this error is coming when I am validating the query. what is the best way to fetch result sets using cognos framework manager from a db2 stored procedure which can return me the paid_strt_dt and paid_end_dt from the above code.

Comment: I've never used DB2 stored procs with Cognos, but I can tell you that Cognos can only access one resultset.   In framework manager, did you set up the parameters?

Comment: Thanks ! you are right , Cognos FM can only fetch resultset. So I used cursors in my DB2 procedure.